# Paperback book from the 60s or 70s about divers who go to Atlantis

Tags: identification-request

I would have read this about 1978 from my teacher's classroom. In it, divers (a man and a woman) dive into the ocean and end up in an underwater city. At the end, the underwater people put them back into their diving suits and make them go into a room which it fills up with water. Then, a door opens to let them out.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please see our [identification-request wiki](/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] further information into your question. For example, do you remember anything about the cover? How about the size (page count, thickness, cover area, mass, etc.)? What language was this in? Where would you have been located, geographically? (Even a country may help). Are you sure it was specifically Atlantis (per your question's title) or might have been a generic underwater city? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Were there illustrations? (If so, what style?) Approximately what age group would this book have been aimed at? Do you remember how the divers were related to/knew each other? How about where the setting was, geographically? (The ocean the divers go into, the land the come from/go to at the end, etc.) Do you remember anything about how the underwater people, or their city, was described? Note that you don't have to know answers to all of these questions - or even any of them - but any detail may be the crucial one for someone trying to identify your book for you.

Comment: Oh man, it was a thicker book written more YA or even adult level. I was in Kansas. The front cover was drawn with divers above a domed city.  No illustrations as it was written like a novel. They were in some type of apartment at some point. And that's all I can recall.

Comment: Please [edit] details into your question so it is as complete as possible